# Ordering the query results based on the order given inside the IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

I would like to order the result set of an sql query based on the order inside the IN clause example:

```
select * from Employee where EmpID='Eng' and DeptID IN ('Software','Mech','Aero','Civil'),
```

for the above query I would like to order the result set in the order 1. Software, 2. Mech, 3. Aero, 4. Civil

Comment: Ordering can be ASC or DESC like this : select * from Employee where EmpID='Eng' and DeptID IN ('Software','Mech','Aero','Civil') ORDER BY ColumnName ASC|DESC

Comment: how come your deptId is like this ? you can specify column nam ein the order by like `order by deptid` asc

Answer (score 5):

In Oracle, use `instr()` or `case`:

```
select *
from Employee
where EmpID='Eng' and DeptID IN ('Software','Mech','Aero','Civil')
order by instr('Software,Mech,Aero,Civil', DeptId)
```

This should also work in DB2.

The `case` form will also work in both databases, but is longer:

```
order by (case DeptID when 'Software' then 1
                      when 'Mech' then 2
                      when 'Aero' then 3
                      when 'Civil' then 4
          end)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can maintain the order in a virtual column and use the input in table or using with clause

```
 with subject as 
 (select 1 ord,'Software' as sub from dual
  union 
  select 2 ord,'Mech' as sub from dual
  union
  select 3 ord,'Aero' as sub from dual
  union
  select 4 ord,'Civil' as sub from dual)

select e.* from Employee,subject
where EmpID='Eng'
and DeptID=subject.sub
order by subject.ord
```

Comment: I prefer this type of solution over an `ORDER BY CASE...` just because it reads as if everything were a normal table.  I'm always curious about whether it might result in faster ordering times, although I haven't had a large enough set (or the right machine) to check up on that.